# SandCastle generate doc. from website

Tags: vb.net, sandcastle

I am trying to generate documentation for a WebSite, but, I don't have a project, in other words, I just go in Visual Studio and I Open a WebSite, I can't generate the XML documentation from this web project style:

[image]

And, I see in [that](http://www.ewoodruff.us/sandcastletools/) documentation I need to put this:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        compilerOptions="/docpath:C:\Publish\Docs"
        type="EWSoftware.CodeDom.VBCodeProviderWithDocs,
              EWSoftware.CodeDom, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
              PublicKeyToken=d633d7d5b41cbb65">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Ok, but when i put this in my web.config, and When I try to build, the compiler return a lot of errors, like that:

```
error BC30451: 'DDtoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
0error BC30451: 'HojetoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'CCtoDD' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30451: 'DataDiff' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'AddDiastoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'AddDiastoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'QueryDB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'AddDiastoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'QueryDB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30451: 'Truncate' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlDataReader' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30451: 'QueryDB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlConnection' is not defined.
error BC30002: Type 'SqlCommand' is not defined.
error BC30451: 'HojetoCC' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

And, When I remove this, the code is compiled normaly ;x

And, I have tried to create a web project whit this code, BUt, I got the same error..
How I can generate the documentation of this web syte project ??

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a bug in the VisualBasic compiler (according to the Sandcastle documentation) you need to add all imports manually. Even essential imports like `System` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. Here is an example of my web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
 <compilers>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" 
      compilerOptions="/docpath:C:\Sandcastle\XML /imports:System,System.Resources,System.Web,Microsoft.VisualBasic,..."
      type="EWSoftware.CodeDom.VBCodeProviderWithDocs, EWSoftware.CodeDom, 
      Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d633d7d5b41cbb65">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
  </compiler>
 </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

When you add all your needed imports, then these errors don't affect the publishing process. Although, there could be still some compile errors when you publish your project. I had problems with the impicit assignment of datatypes in all my for each loops.

I had to change my loops to
`For Each i as Integer = 0 In List(Of Object)`
After that it all worked perfectly.